# 2N7002 Continuous drain current?

Tags: power, current, mosfet, datasheet

I'm currently looking for some MOSFET's to do some RGB LED lighting with using PWM. I found the 2N7002 in SOT-23 packaging ([datasheet](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/302/2N7002-99839.pdf)). According to the datasheet the MOSFET can handle a continuous drain of 300mA. My current draw will be about 200mA. I'm also seeing elsewhere though on the internet that typical current draw should be 115mA.

Now I really don't understand most of the datasheet but the basics; so am I ok to use these for my application?

Comment: See figure 3 in the datasheet.

Comment: "I really don't understand most of the datasheet"

Comment: I didn't get it at first either but if you look around a bit and figure out what `Tp` is then it's pretty self-explanatory. `Tp` represents the high-time for your PWM signal. So looking at figure 3, it tells you information about continuous drain current as a function of the duty cycle you drive it with *and* the drain-source voltage of the MOSFET. If you do not understand what the the drain-source voltage is then you should read up on [MOSFET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOSFET#Modes_of_operation)s a bit more first.

Comment: Although for switching applications the specified Vds doesn't apply.

Answer (score 2):

2N7002 is **not** a very suitable part for this application. Assuming you even have 10V to drive it, the power dissipation (worst case) of 360mW is a bit much for an SOT-23 even if you use 2-oz copper 1 inch square etc.

Something like an [AO3418](http://www.aosmd.com/res/data_sheets/AO3418.pdf) would be a lot better- even with 2.5V drive it will dissipate well under 10mW conducting 200mA, and it's not that expensive. The only downside is that it has more gate charge (not usually a problem for PWM at reasonable frequencies), and that it is only rated for 30V rather than the 60V of the geriatric 2N7002.